# Troubles with an MS-Access Listbox linked to a YES/NO type field

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba

I have a form with 2 listboxs (list1 and list2) that displays the values from 2 YES/NO type fields. On the table the field data is represented by checkboxs but in the listbox it displays as True/False 
I also have 2 comboboxes with Yes and No values which are used to populate/edit the field in the table.

I am trying to edit the VBA code of this form in such a way that the 2 listboxes (and values in the field) can not be true at the same time. i.e if a user selects true on combo1 and hits save, the program will check the value in list2 and, if its also true, display an error message and exit the sub.

i have found that the values are actually saved as 0's and -1's in the list box but my problem is that the value of the list box doesnt change even after changing the value on the table. i.e even though the True/False Values changes accordinly when the value on the table field is changed, the 0's and 1's dont change (found this out by msgboxing the values on the listbox) and this makes it impossible to compare values before saving.

An example of the code i am using is below

```
...   

 List2.Requery
'MsgBox List2

 'MsgBox Combo1
If Combo1 = "True" And List2.Value = "-1" Then
MsgBox "List1 and List2 cannot be TRUE at the same time. Please adjust or cancel edit"     
Exit Sub
Else
myr.Edit
myr![Y/Nfield] = Combo1
myr.Update


Set myr = Nothing 'Close the recordeset 


End If

...
```

(the ... means there are codes before and after this bit)

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled as to why you need two List Box controls *and* two Combo Box controls. Normal UI design would be to have the Yes/No fields represented by Check Box controls. If you really want to use "True/False" or "Yes/No" Combo Box controls then that's fine I guess, but what purpose do the List Box controls serve?

Comment: @GordThompson I use the list box to hold a query for the table and thereby display the yes/no field for a particular project. Using a checkbox doesnt allow me use queries (or maybe i dont know how)

Comment: @GordThompson i dont know if this is allowed here but is there a way i could contact you? would like to explain the system i am creating to you so that you can tell me how you would do it differently. (seeing as the two list box method i used is puzzling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just incase one comes to this later and really needs answer here's how i solved this...

instead of using the list2.value property (refer to code in question) i used list.itemdata(0) which points to the first column of my listbox

and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your List Box Properties values.
On the Properties Windows then choose Data tab, You need to check the following properties :

1. Row Source Type, should be Table/Query
2. Row Source, should be filled with your corresponding table name
3. Bound Column, should be filled with your column index of your table that you wish to view on the listbox

Comment: Did you refresh your form after you update the table?

Comment: No... i just requery the listbox